# Connect LG 25UB55-B to Dell XPS L502x

Tags: linux, laptop, display, hdmi, optimus

I'm going to buy LG 25UB55-B monitor, which will be connected to my Dell XPS L502x notebook.

But after some investigation I'm a little bit confused and unsure if it will work. There are several doubts:

1. Dell XPS L502x is supported by nVidia card with Optimus technology. Is it a problem for connecting an external monitor under Linux?
2. Is it a problem for this "outdated" notebook to support 2560x1080 resolution?
3. Should I rely on hdmi or display port?

Answer (score 1):

1. It should work without any problem.
2. It should be fine as long as you're not using your laptop for graphics-intensive games.
3. There is no real difference between HDMI and DisplayPort at that resolution and refresh rate (60Hz).